# Has anyone used the url property in a typeahead inputtext?

Tags: url, xpages, typeahead

I am trying to use a typeahead functionality within an inputtext-field.
Instead of populating the values by using a fixed list or a DBColumn (which is way to slow for more than thousands of entries), I would like to use the url parameter of the typeahead properties.

What I have done so far is that:

```
<xp:inputText value="#{docEntry.namUsers}" id="namUsers">
    <xp:typeAhead mode="external" valueMarkup="false" minChars="3" var="namEntries" frequency="1" maxValues="10" id="typeAheadNamUsers">
        <xp:this.url><![CDATA[#{javascript:"http://server/databse.nsf/view?ReadViewEntries&OutputFormat=JSON&StartKey=" + getComponent("namUsers").getAttributes().get("value");}]]></xp:this.url>
    </xp:typeAhead>
</xp:inputText>
```

When entering the minimum required characters I can see that a GET-request is fired. And this GET-request returns the desired content of the view.

But I didn't find any way to fetch the returned information in order to parse the content and give a valid list to the typeahead element.

Has anyone tried using the url property of the typeahead element?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use the *url* parameter of the typeahead this way. The parameter is only a configuration parameter for the initialisation of the typeahead widget and will not get updated with your server side code.

If you look in the firebug console you can see that there is an URL parameter named *$$value* which is automatically added to the url you have defined (containing the characters for the lookup itself).

The response for the Typeahead needs to be simple HTML code:

```
<ul>
   <li>Result 1</li>
   <li>Result 2</li>
   <li>Result 3</li>
   <li>...</li>
</ul>
```

[It can be changed for display purposes, but it needs to be HTML]

There is no JSON / no XML for external requests.

You could create a *$$ViewTemplate* (HTML content) for your view to return the required format, and f.e. add a redirection agent:

```
Option Public
Option Declare

Sub Initialize
    Dim session As New NotesSession
    Dim doc As NotesDocument
    Dim hlp

    Set doc = session.Documentcontext
    hlp = Split( doc.QUERY_STRING_DECODED(0), "$$value=" )
    Print "[http://example.com/YourDB.nsf/View?OpenView&startKey=" & hlp(1) & "]"

End Sub
```

Then you can set the url to your Agent instead to the view:

```
<xp:typeAhead mode="external" valueMarkup="false" minChars="3"
   frequency="1" maxValues="10" id="typeAheadNamUsers"
   url="http://example.com/YourDB.nsf/RedirectAgent?OpenAgent">
</xp:typeAhead>
```

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK the data expected from that URL needs to be "collection ready", meaning a list of values separated by a delimiter (comma or newline). ?ReadViewEntries doesn't deliver that format, so you want to use a HTML passthru view instead.
I would challenge you assumption. If your database for the lookup is on the same server, what makes you presume that adding HTTP latency will be faster than a @DbColumn? If it is a different server it would be an interesting test -- besides it would be better anyhow to keep the value lookup on the same server.
Another question: is the user experience with thousands of potential values in a typeahead list really what is efficient, effective and pleasant?

Comment: Hi stwissel, thanks for your response. Just for a quick feedback on your question: @DBLookup on a view with 16000 entries -> 10.8seconds. Same view but with ?ReadViewEntries -> 1.2seconds. And the other thing concerning the user experience: the result list is going to be limited at 20 entries.

Comment: I've been using @DbLookup with 100K Domino Directory without problems. Did you try a second time (was the view indexed)?

Comment: Hi Panu Haaramo, using this @DBLookup-way I am ending up with 64k errors. And as I already mentioned: it *IS DEFINITELY* far too slow compared with ?ReadViewEntries. I am wondering, why I cannot use the JSON ready answer to pass it as a value list for the typeahead functionality.

Comment: The JSON from readViewEntries is simply not in the format that the typeahead can digest. I suggest you create a view and label it "treat as HTML", so you have 100% control on what it renders

Comment: @PantelisBotsas Your entries are suprisingly big if you hit 64K limit (do we still have that with SSJS??) with 20 entries. I'm just wondering how it can take 10.8 seconds with such a small amounts you mentioned.